# Potential memory leak with custom method, doesn't make sense

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have this method:

```
-(NSString *)scrambleWordGenerator: (NSUInteger)length {
    NSMutableString *scrambledWord = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [self.arrayOfCharacters count];
        NSString *randomCharacter = [NSString stringWithString:[self.arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
        [scrambledWord insertString:randomCharacter atIndex:i];
    }
    NSString *finalWord = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:scrambledWord];
    [scrambledWord release];
    return finalWord;
}
```

It works, swimmingly in fact, however upon using Xcode's "Analysis" feature, it says that `finalWord` has a potential memory leak.

I thought when creating a `NSString` with a prefab `init` method that the string will be autoreleased. What am I missing?  Below is a screen grab of the error:

[image]

**edit**

The method now looks like this:

```
-(NSString *)scrambleWordGenerator: (NSUInteger)length {
    NSMutableString *scrambledWord = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [self.arrayOfCharacters count];
        NSString *randomCharacter = [NSString stringWithString:[self.arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
        [scrambledWord insertString:randomCharacter atIndex:i];
    }
    NSString *finalWord = [NSString stringWithString:scrambledWord];
    [scrambledWord release];
    return finalWord;
}
```

And no more errors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the moment you use `alloc`, you're responsible for releasing it - either by `release` or by moving it to autorelease pool via `autorelease`.

It would be on the autorelease pool if you used `[NSString stringWithString:]` instead.

Comment: Hint: you could replace the last line with `return [finalWord autorelease];`

Comment: You both are amazing, thank you so much! I used Simon's suggestion, but Costique, I will consider that for other methods!

Comment: @LumBerry: The explicit `autorelease` in the `return` statement can be helpful for future readability, especially in a longer method. On the other hand, you have to make sure when writing it initially that you don't send `autorelease` to an unowned object.